# Sorting an array of arrays according to a certain value within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an output from a function like, It basically contains an Id and value having an array of arrays. Here it goes:

```
[
  {
    "centre": "5f8a8da57cb24b64b69c430c",
    "value": [
      [
        "TOTAL",
        4
      ],
      [
        "A",
        1
      ],
      [
        "B",
        1
      ],
      [
        "C",
        0
      ],
      [
        "D",
        1
      ],
      [
        "E",
        1
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "centre": "1cbafa99d8c77251bea30f11",
    "value": [
      [
        "TOTAL",
        4
      ],
      [
        "A",
        2
      ],
      [
        "B",
        1
      ],
      [
        "C",
        1
      ],
      [
        "D",
        0
      ],
      [
        "E",
        0
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to sort all the values according to the second value of array in the descending manner and if the values are matching then sorting it according to alphabetical order from the first value of array. I'm not sure how to do such sort of sorting which comes under in an object having array of arrays.

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "centre": "5f8a8da57cb24b64b69c430c",
    "value": [
      [
        "TOTAL",
        4
      ],
      [
        "A",
        1
      ],
      [
        "B",
        1
      ],
      [
        "D",
        1
      ],
      [
        "E",
        1
      ],
      [
        "C",
        0
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "centre": "1cbafa99d8c77251bea30f11",
    "value": [
      [
        "TOTAL",
        4
      ],
      [
        "A",
        2
      ],
      [
        "B",
        1
      ],
      [
        "C",
        1
      ],
      [
        "D",
        0
      ],
      [
        "E",
        0
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you want values array in decs order?

Comment: where is the difference? what have you tried?

Comment: @KetanRamteke yes in desc order according to second value and when second value is same then alphabetical sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [
  {
centre: "5f8a8da57cb24b64b69c430c",
value: [["TOTAL", 4],["A", 1],["B", 1],["C", 0],["D", 1],["E", 1],],
  },
  {
centre: "1cbafa99d8c77251bea30f11",
value: [["TOTAL", 4],["A", 1],["G", 1],["K", 0],["D", 1],["B", 1],],
  },
];

let sol = data.map((d) => {
  d.value.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
  d.value.sort((a, b) => parseInt(b[1] - a[1]));
  return d;
});


console.log(sol);
```

Comment: okay, first we are iterating through the given object array using ```map``` function, then comes the sorting, here we are just taking the elements of ```value``` and sorting them and after that returning the object with sorted ```value``` array in it.

Comment: It's still not sorting alphabetically. Check with the value: [["TOTAL", 4],["A", 1],["G", 1],["C", 0],["D", 1],["E", 1],],

Comment: it's giving output like value: [["TOTAL", 4], ["A", 1], ["G", 1], ["D", 1], ["E", 1], ["C", 0]]

Comment: Can you post few edge cases to test.

Comment: Just try to replace the alphabets having the value same. That's how we can check for alphabetical order while having same values

Comment: check with this value: [["TOTAL", 4],["A", 1],["G", 1],["K", 0],["D", 1],["B", 1],],

Comment: sorted value should be : [["TOTAL",4],["A",1],["B",1],["D",1],["G",1],["K",0]]}] ?
if yes then code is updated.

Comment: Yes, that's how it needs to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224723/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-stark).

Comment: It won't sort the array when we have something like AA, AB, AC ,AD. I mean, If first letter of the text is same then it won't look on the second letter

Comment: you can easily fix that with ```lacaleCompare()```

Comment: One last thing, what if i want to fix that TOTAL as the very first field and sort the rest of the value. @Ketan Ramteke

Comment: Hmm, filter out the TOTAL array and then concat the remaining sorted elements to Total.

Comment: Got it, we can use shift() and unshift()

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript `sort` function.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    centre: '5f8a8da57cb24b64b69c430c',
    value: [['TOTAL', 4], ['A', 1], ['B', 1], ['C', 0], ['D', 1], ['E', 1]],
  },
  {
    centre: '1cbafa99d8c77251bea30f11',
    value: [['TOTAL', 4], ['A', 2], ['B', 1], ['C', 1], ['D', 0], ['E', 0]],
  },
];

const res = arr.map(item => {
  const {value, centre} = item;
  value.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
      return b[0] - a[0];
    } else {
      return b[1] - a[1];
    }
  });
  return {centre, value};
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If numbers are not equal, will sort relative to them, otherwise relative to strings:

```
function numComparator(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
}

function strComparator(a, b) {
    return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 0;
}

items = [["E",0],["A",2],["B",1],["C",1],["TOTAL",4],["D",0]];
items.sort((a, b) => a[1] === b[1] ? strComparator(a, b) : numComparator(a, b));
```

Thus, items are sorted relative to numbers, and items with the same numbers are additionally sorted by strings.

Also note that `sort` is modifying an original array, not creating a new array!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr=[{centre:"5f8a8da57cb24b64b69c430c",value:[["TOTAL",4],["A",1],["B",1],["C",0],["D",1],["E",1]]},{centre:"1cbafa99d8c77251bea30f11",value:[["TOTAL",4],["A",2],["B",1],["C",1],["D",0],["E",0]]}];

arr.forEach((e) => {
    e.value.sort((f,s) => {
        if(s[1] === f[1])
            return f[0].codePointAt(0) - s[0].codePointAt(0) 
        return s[1]-f[1]}
)
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This one also don't sort lexicographically.